# Create my personnel Cloud on my personnel server

Tags: server, cloud, host

I Would like to know if someone have any idea to Create my own Cloud, soon I'll buy a professional server and I Would like to create my own cloud. I also want to be able to host web sites and data . Thank you for your help

Comment: You have to provide more information than that. This question is equivalent to saying "I want to build my own software to sell to customers." What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to build your own cloud or are you asking about how to use cloud services that already exist?

Comment: thank you for your response,I want to build my own cloud ! it is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Response to your comment. This is possible. I would look into to the open source hyper-visor framework called Xen. The reason is every cloud provider hosts their own hardware. They mostly also use some virtualization technology. For a "lower" startup cost, look into Xen as it is open source and used by many cloud providers in the business today (AWS, Digital Ocean, Rackspace, Verizon) Understand that this is a huge undertaking and requires a lot of capital, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

http://www.xenproject.org/